# SQL IN AND NOT IN on same request

Tags: sql

The table contains:

```
uid       roles_target_id

417       admin_site

417       membre_du_site

3         admin_site

4         admin_site

5         membre_du_site
etc
```

I am having a request that filter rows having the selected roles:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid AS uid
FROM
{users_field_data} u
LEFT OUTER JOIN {user__roles} ur ON ur.entity_id = u.uid
WHERE (ur.roles_target_id IN ('gestionnaire', 'gestionnaire_axes_de_recherche', 'gestionnaire_services', 'admin_site', 'gestionnaire_projet'))
```

417, 3,4 is kept

How can exclude 417 because it is also "membre_du_site" ?
NOT IN has no effect

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid AS uid
FROM
{users_field_data} u
LEFT OUTER JOIN {user__roles} ur ON ur.entity_id = u.uid
WHERE (ur.roles_target_id IN ('gestionnaire', 'gestionnaire_axes_de_recherche', 'gestionnaire_services', 'admin_site', 'gestionnaire_projet')) AND (ur.roles_target_id NOT IN ('membre_du_site'))
```

EDIT

Trying with exist/not exist

```
SELECT u.uid AS uid FROM users_field_data u WHERE (u.uid > '1') AND (u.login < '1586693034') AND (u.login != '0')
```

retrieve 417,418,422 and other numbers

```
SELECT ur.entity_id AS uid FROM user__roles ur WHERE (ur.roles_target_id IN ('membre_du_site'))
```

contains 417, 418 and other numbers

```
SELECT ur.entity_id AS uid FROM user__roles ur WHERE (ur.roles_target_id IN ('admin_site'))
```

contains 417, 422 and other numbers

```
SELECT u.uid AS uid
FROM
users_field_data u
WHERE (u.uid > '1') AND (u.login < '1586693034') AND (u.login != '0') AND EXISTS (SELECT ur.entity_id AS uid
FROM
user__roles ur
WHERE (ur.roles_target_id IN ('admin_site'))) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ur.entity_id AS uid
FROM
user__roles ur
WHERE (ur.roles_target_id IN ('membre_du_site')))
```

retrieve nothing !?

Comment: Where clauses are evaluated per row, if `ur.roles_target_id` is in the first list (eg `admin_site`), then it is not in the second list, so it evaluates to true. If you want rows in `users_field_data` that match (or not match) one or more rows in `users__roles`, then you should use `(not) exists` instead of joining and using `in`/`not in`.

Comment: The `NOT IN` is having an effect. Select `uid` and `roles_target_id`, you'll see that `417` is being returned because there is a record with `uid` = `417` and `roles_target_id` of `admin_site`. Your `WHERE` clause explicitly allows records with a `roles_target_id` of `admin_site`, so `417` gets returned in the results.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel i have edited my question if you could have a look

Comment: I would go back to your original query.  although I think you do not need the second part.  If you write a SQL statement that reads: `WHERE ur.roles_target_id in ('A','B','C')` you shouldn't need an opposing filter that says where `ur.roles_target_id NOT IN` some other list.  its redundant.   you may want to switch to an inner join if you want to be more exclusive with the records you return.  the `left outer join` will return a row even if the record doesn't match on the right side.

Comment: what database platform are you working on, sometimes that matters for the SQL syntax that works best? MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL? thanks!

Comment: In each of the queries you try you also introduce new conditions that did not exist in the first query. You should also post the correct column names: *The table contains:...* is about which table? If it is about {user__roles} shouldn't the column's name be `entity_id ` and not `uid`?

Comment: @Glenn Ferrie mariadb

Comment: In your recent edit you forget to correlate the `exists`/`not exists` with the entity you're testing for. You should only check for `user__roles` that match the current user you're evaluating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where clauses are evaluated per row, if `ur.roles_target_id` is in the first list (eg `admin_site`), then it is not in the second list, so it evaluates to true. If you want rows in `users_field_data` that match (or not match) one or more rows in `users__roles`, then you should use `(not) exists` instead of joining and using `in`/`not in`.

Make sure that the query in the `(not) exists` is correlated with the outer query by matching on the `uid`:

```sql
SELECT u.uid AS uid
FROM users_field_data u
WHERE u.uid > '1' 
AND u.login < '1586693034' 
AND u.login != '0' 
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT ur.entity_id AS uid
  FROM user__roles ur
  WHERE ur.entity_id = u.uid
  AND ur.roles_target_id IN ('admin_site')
) 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT ur.entity_id AS uid
  FROM user__roles ur
  WHERE ur.entity_id = u.uid
  AND ur.roles_target_id IN ('membre_du_site')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return only `uid`s I don't see the need for a join.
All the data you need is in `{user__roles}` so use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ur.entity_id AS uid
FROM {user__roles} ur 
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM {user__roles} 
    WHERE entity_id = ur.entity_id 
      AND roles_target_id IN ('gestionnaire', 'gestionnaire_axes_de_recherche', 'gestionnaire_services', 'admin_site', 'gestionnaire_projet')
  )
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM {user__roles} 
    WHERE entity_id = ur.entity_id 
      AND roles_target_id NOT IN ('gestionnaire', 'gestionnaire_axes_de_recherche', 'gestionnaire_services', 'admin_site', 'gestionnaire_projet')
  )
```

Comment: thanks i believe that approach is working too but the one above also